# login auth didn't work onlie in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make login and register at my laravel website , and i have been used the laravel make auth , it's working very good at local host but when i have uploaded it it's not . It doesn't read the auth name or anything just it's regsiter new user but can't login or show the error message or anything.

please i need help ? and here's my register blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
 <!-- Modal Signup -->
<div class="modal fade style-base-modal" id="modal-signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalSignupLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="inner-container clearfix">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title email-icon" id="modalSignupLabel">@lang('messages.Create-your-Account')</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-7 no-padding">
                <form   accept-charset="UTF-8"   class="form-style-base" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">   
                 {{ csrf_field() }} 
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-border no-padding  form-group-style-sign {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg form-control-style-sign" placeholder="@lang('messages.UserName')"  name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"/>
                       @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                         @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-border no-padding  form-group-style-sign {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg form-control-style-sign" placeholder="@lang('messages.Email')"  name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" />
                     @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                      @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-border no-padding  form-group-style-sign {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg form-control-style-sign" placeholder="@lang('messages.Password')" name="password">
                     @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                     @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group no-bottom-border no-padding  form-group-style-sign {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg form-control-style-sign" placeholder="@lang('messages.Re-password')" name="password_confirmation">
                     @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                     @endif
                </div>





              <div class="required-fields text-right spacer-bottom-5">
                *@lang('messages.Required-fields')
              </div>

              <div>
               <!-- <div class="checkbox">
                  <label class="btn-link small">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Iscriviti" value="1" /> Subscribe to the newsletter
                  </label>
                </div>-->
               <!--  <div class="checkbox">
                  <label class="btn-link small">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="1" /> I agree to the policies of the <a class="btn-link" href="#">privacy</a>
                  </label>
                </div> -->
              </div>

             <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> @lang('messages.create-account')
                </button>
            </div>
            <!--<p class="text-center small no-margin">
                <label class="member-label">Already are you member? </label><a class="btn-link" href="signin.html">Sign in</a>
            </p>-->
        </form>          </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 spacer-30">
                    <div class="text-center">
          <h4 class="no-margin-top   social-sign">
           @lang('messages.socialnetwork')<br>@lang('messages.accountSignin')
          </h4>
          <div class="socials btn-group clearfix">

            <a class="btn-social btn-facebook " href="redirect">  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></i> </a>


          </div>
        </div>

                  </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end sign up -->
@endsection
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you see any error message on storage/logs/laravel.log file?